# my bootstrsp is not navbar is not toggling on smaller screen size

Tags: html

i'm new to bootstrap. have been trying to figure out where i got it wrong, when i click on the  collapse button to expand the menu on mobile-screen size, its not displaying my nav-item

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>bootstrap-tutorials</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/fontawesome.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light menu">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testimonals</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Faq</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what Bootstrap version you are using ?

Comment: i don't see bootstrap connection